# Grub-customizer trying to use `KDE su` - Cannot login

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader, group, kubuntu

I would like to use Grub Customizer, but I cannot start it. After entering the administrator password,

[image]

it asks again for it:

[image]

(see update below: I guess the first image shows an interface that is not the normal one for administration access.)

I have created wheel group and added user to  it but that doesn't change anything.

---

### UPDATES:

**After comment by @mashuptwice saying to use `sudo`:**

Typing in terminal `sudo grub-customizer` it works fine.

`grub-customizer` in terminal works too but with a different interface for password then the one displayed when executing the launcher: this one shows the normal "KDE Agent" title

[image]

***As said in another comment by @mashuptwice: the first and second images show KDE su instead of the normal KDE Agent!***

After testing more, it seems that any attempt to launch Grub Customizer from the application launcher —even with a modified command—  triggers this problem.

Comment: Note: kubuntu uses the `sudo` group instead of the `wheel` group. You might want to start the program from command line via `sudo grub-customizer`

Comment: @mashuptwice - That is the solution. But even `grub-customizer` works in terminaI, but not in the launcher. That is very odd: the default command behind the grub-customizer launcher is `grub-customizer`, and it shows an interface for password (first image) that is not relating to `sudo`: what is that doing? The same happens if I try `pkexec`. But `sudo` works as you said.  `grub-customizer` works in terminaI too, and the interface for pass is a bit different. I will update the question.

Comment: That is weird, does the same happen with other root GUI applications, like partition managers?

Comment: One thing that strikes me is that your authentication window says `KDE su` in the title, while mine says `PolicyKit1 KDE Agent`. Note that I am on Arch at the moment, but can check a Kubuntu machine later.

Comment: @mashuptwice - `am on Arch at the moment, but can check a Kubuntu machine later` - don"t worry, It's a bug in my system I guess. I'll just use sudo for now (`pkexec` has the same problem) and will look for askubuntu assistance when the system reaches stable phase.

Comment: @mashuptwice - **There was no problem with KDE Partition manager, sorry. I was wrong.** The problem was with the file `/usr/share/applications/grub-customizer.desktop`, which contained the line `X-KDE-SubstituteUID=true`. I don't know what that is but commenting/removing it fixes this.

Comment: Glad you've found the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems that any attempt to launch Grub Customizer from the
> application launcher —even with a modified command—  triggers this
> problem

The problem was thus with Grub Customizer desktop-launcher file (`/usr/share/applications/grub-customizer.desktop`), which contained the line

```
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=true
```

I don't know what that is (it entails the use of `kdesu`, which shouldn't be the way to go here it seems) — but commenting/removing it fixes this.

Such lines in the desktop launcher files add new conditions which are applied to the command in the `Exec` line (and these conditions cannot be edited through the KDE Menu Editor/Edit applications options, for example).